# How do I know who to trust as I start producing a book?

Tags: editing, story, book-cover

I am writing a book at age 10-11, by myself. I have some people like my teacher and parents helping to edit, but I don't have anyone I can trust to help me (without screwing it up). I also don't know if I should do the cover art physically or digitally.

How does all this work?

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations on starting your first book at age 10! Your parents and teacher are invaluable help on editing. It sounds like they aren't advising you on the publication yet.

From my perspective, at your age, your parents are critical to publishing. Speaking from my own experience as a parent, my child has created amazing work at an early age and yet we've been incredibly careful to protect her privacy in any publications.

Beyond parents and teachers, another great resource might be your school or community librarians and local bookstore owners. Some librarians and bookstore owners might be well connected to the book publishing world and at the least can help you find resources on it.

Also, look for programs and competitions aimed at young authors. Some might help lead to publishing and at the least will provide feedback and writing and experience.

If you're in the United States, one of the best programs I've seen for getting feedback and improving the visibility of creative work is a program from the National Parent Teachers Assocation (PTA) called [Reflections](https://www.pta.org/home/programs/reflections). If your local school has a PTA, reach out to the leaders of that organization to see how you can participate. If not, I suggestion using the resources the National PTA shares with students of your age on their website as one model of how you might proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do the cover art at all. If you intend to get a literary agent, or submit to a publisher, they will reject your manuscript immediately if you provide cover art.

That is not your job. That is the job of the publisher, and they will employ professional artists and technologists to build the cover; and it is very complex issue to build a cover that sells, involving psychology and a form of visual story-telling all on its own. It is not for amateurs.

If you intend to self-publish, I'd work with a digital medium; eventually you need to be able to print it, or send it to someone to print it.

As for advice on how to write, I suggest you stick to the professionals, people that have done this for a living, for decades, and have written about it.

Stephen King has good book, "On Writing". Orson Scott Card produces excellent books on writing. Look for highly rated books on the craft of writing fiction, and read them.

I began by reading about a dozen of them; some were better than others.

Here are some I found:

"On Writing: A Memoir of the Craft" by Stephen King.

"Bird by Bird: Some Instructions on Writing and Life" by Anne Lamott.

"Stein On Writing: A Master Editor Shares His Craft, Techniques, and Strategies" by Sol Stein.

"Story: Substance, Structure, Style, and the Principles of Screenwriting" by Robert McKee.

"The Art of Fiction: Notes on Craft for Young Writers" by John Gardner.

"Self-Editing for Fiction Writers: How to Edit Yourself Into Print" by Renni Browne and Dave King.

"Writing Fiction: A Guide to Narrative Craft" by Janet Burroway.

"Characters & Viewpoint": Card shows how to create realistic and interesting characters.
How to Write Science Fiction & Fantasy", also Orson Scott Card.

Note Orson Scott Card also wrote "Elements of Fiction Writing - Writing Fantasy & Science Fiction": As part of the "Elements of Fiction Writing" series, and that series has several books that were useful.

The problem with parents, friends and teachers, and anybody that you personally know, is often they want to encourage you, and don't want to hurt your feelings by telling you when something is bad or not going to get published. Their attempts to be kind make it hard for them to tell you that you aren't doing it right, or doing it well.

You are better served by the books, if you read the correct way to do it, hopefully you can realize you are **not** doing it that way, and you need to learn and change how you are doing it.

It can be very difficult for an adult or a friend or an older sibling to find a way to tell you something negative about your writing. So it is very difficult for you to get completely honest feedback.

I personally was much better served by reading the books, realizing my mistakes on my own, in private, and getting over them and getting better at it. The authors of these books are not trying to discourage you, they are just trying to tell you how things work in the real world, the obstacles to getting published (or just writing a great story) that you won't be able to get around.

You can look these books up, they are probably still on Amazon, and get some descriptions of them, and see if they appeal to you.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to finding someone to trust, think about what you are trusting them **with**:

- Your money? That's easy. Do not pay **anyone** any amount of money to get your book published. There's no "only if you are sure you can trust them" exception to this rule. The author does not pay to be published. Exception: if you are a financially secure adult who would gain valuable benefits from being published you might choose to buy that, just as adults buy couches or plane tickets. Everyone else is either an amateur (no money changes hands) or is getting paid. You do not pay. As for the payments you receive, it's possible a publisher would not want to contract with you directly; your parents are the ideal people to receive the money for you.
- Your idea? Ideas are infinite, and only valuable to those willing to do the work that follows. Your reputation? You don't have one. Don't worry about these two at all.
- Your words and work? The chances of someone publishing your stuff as theirs is incredibly low. More likely is that someone will get you excited, cause you to work a lot, and then in the end nothing will come of it. That work won't be wasted, though: you will have improved and you will also probably still have the words you wrote and can use with someone else. If someone says they'll edit and then they don't, well, you find someone else to edit. It's a long slow journey to being an overnight success. Writing is working, and getting something published is another kind of working, and they both need to be done.

It's natural to feel nervous and overwhelmed. When you do, strive for precision. In this case, it's "trust them with what?". Next time you're struggling with a big question, work to lasso it down to a smaller one. Smaller questions can be answered, often quite easily.